# How to sign out Google authentication in GoogleFit SDK?

Tags: android, google-signin

I check if user's account has OAuth permission to Fitness API.

```
private boolean hasOAuthPermission() {
    FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = getFitnessSignInOptions();
    return GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()), fitnessOptions);
}
```

Then if it return false, launch the Google Sign In activity to request OAuth permission for the user by using this method:

```
private void requestOAuthPermission() {
    FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = getFitnessSignInOptions();
    GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
            this,
            REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,
            GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
            fitnessOptions);
}
```

It show dialog to choose user and allow permission.

How can I sign out Google Sign In, to able to show account dialog again?

Answer (score 0):

You can sign out by using this:

```
Fitness.getConfigClient(context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)).disableFit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of [Google Fit](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/disconnect)

You would find that you just need to do:

```
Fitness.getConfigClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).disableFit()
```

That is basically, *same behaviour as tapping Disconnect from GoogleFit* (Quote from the link)