# Signing out of GoogleFit

Tags: java, android-studio, google-fit

I have tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143933/how-to-sign-out-google-authentication-in-googlefit-sdk) however the recommended does not do anything:

```
Fitness.getConfigClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).disableFit()
```

How I authenticate with Google:

```
if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(this, REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                fitnessOptions);
    } else {
        subscribe();
    }



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE) {
                subscribe();
            }
        }
    }



public void subscribe() {
        
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
    }
```

I need to be able to get the google account which was last signed in and provide an option to the user to sign out of their google account.

Answer (score 0):

For disconnecting Google account from your app you should use signOut method from GoogleSignIn which will preserve granted permissions or you can use revokeAccess method to do both signing out and revoke granted permissions:

```
val options = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .addExtension(getFitnessOptions())
    .requestProfile()
    .build()

GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, options).signOut() // or GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, options).revokeAccess()
```